# How can I get time ranges in each unit from two time range in Java using Joda time

Tags: java, jodatime

Let's say I have two time ranges (2014-01-25 10:23:14 -> 2016-09-05 11:43: 55).

I want to get time ranges from above in term of time units like in below:

```
2014-01-25 10:23:14 - 2014-01-25 10:24:00 = second range
2014-01-25 10:24:00 - 2014-01-25 11:00:00 = minute range
2014-01-25 11:00:00 - 2014-01-26 00:00:00 = hour range
2014-01-26 00:00:00 - 2014-02-01 00:00:00 = day range
2014-02-01 00:00:00 - 2016-09-01 00:00:00 = month range
2016-09-01 00:00:00 - 2016-09-05 00:00:00 = day range
2016-09-05 00:00:00 - 2016-09-05 11:00:00 = hour range
2016-09-05 11:00:00 - 2016-09-05 11:43:00 = minute range
2016-09-05 11:43:00 - 2016-09-05 11:43:55 = second range
```

Is it possible to get above kind of ranges using `joda-time`?

Comment: It is not at all clear how you define each range. For example, whiy does the _Day Range_ stat the following day and end a week later? Why does `Month Range` actually cover 7 months?  Etc... if there's a pattern please enlighten us.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. We are storing some statistic information based on their time units. As an example, we are storing a total value in term of per second based, per minute based, per hour based etc in-order to get a better performance. So if I want the total value of something, then I don't need to do calculation on raw data which take some considerable amount of time. Instead of that I can look up on the above mentioned tables and from the client side, I can do the final calculation which is more quicker.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
 package org.kodejava.example.joda;
 import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Duration;
import org.joda.time.Interval;
import org.joda.time.Months;

public class IntervalDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTime startDate = new DateTime();
    DateTime endDate = startDate.plus(Months.months(2));

    //
    // Creates an interval from a start to an end instant.
    //
    Interval interval = new Interval(startDate, endDate);
    System.out.println("Interval = " + interval);
    System.out.println("Start    = " + interval.getStart());
    System.out.println("End      = " + interval.getEnd());

    //
    // Add one more month to the interval
    //
    interval = interval.withEnd(interval.getEnd().plusMonths(1));
    System.out.println("Interval = " + interval);

    //
    // Gets the duration of this time interval
    //
    Duration duration = interval.toDuration();
    System.out.println("Duration = " + duration);
    }
}
```

Result will be like:

```
Interval = 2012-02-28T17:53:36.997/2012-04-28T17:53:36.997
Start    = 2012-02-28T17:53:36.997+08:00
End      = 2012-04-28T17:53:36.997+08:00
Interval = 2012-02-28T17:53:36.997/2012-05-28T17:53:36.997
Duration = PT7776000S
```

Ref: https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-use-the-interval-class-of-joda-time/